# Do you need approval from the FAA for amateur model rocket launches?

Tags: united-states, delaware, faa

I'm building a model rocket that will probably go a maximum of 30km. Do I need special permission from the FAA to do this? I'm in Delaware, U.S.A., and this is a Class 1 Model Rocket. If I do, where can I get started? And do I need a licence or just permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FAA regulates amateur model rocketry under [14 CFR 101, Subpart C](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/part-101/subpart-C).

For a Class 1 model rocket:

> (a) Class 1 - Model Rocket means an amateur rocket that:
>
> (1) Uses no more than 125 grams (4.4 ounces) of propellant;
>
> (2) Uses a slow-burning propellant;
>
> (3) Is made of paper, wood, or breakable plastic;
>
> (4) Contains no substantial metal parts; and
>
> (5) Weighs no more than 1,500 grams (53 ounces), including the propellant.

The following are the general limitations:

> (a) You must operate an amateur rocket in such a manner that it:
>
> (1) Is launched on a suborbital trajectory;
>
> (2) When launched, must not cross into the territory of a foreign
> country unless an agreement is in place between the United States and
> the country of concern;
>
> (3) Is unmanned; and
>
> (4) Does not create a hazard to persons, property, or other aircraft.
>
> (b) The FAA may specify additional operating limitations necessary to
> ensure that air traffic is not adversely affected, and public safety
> is not jeopardized.

And specific requirements for notification are outlined as:

> No person may operate an unmanned rocket other than a Class 1 - Model
> Rocket unless that person gives the following information to the FAA
> ATC facility nearest to the place of intended operation no less than
> 24 hours before and no more than three days before beginning the
> operation:
>
> (a) The name and address of the operator; except when there are
> multiple participants at a single event, the name and address of the
> person so designated as the event launch coordinator, whose duties
> include coordination of the required launch data estimates and
> coordinating the launch event;
>
> (b) Date and time the activity will begin;
>
> (c) Radius of the affected area on the ground in nautical miles;
>
> (d) Location of the center of the affected area in latitude and
> longitude coordinates;
>
> (e) Highest affected altitude;
>
> (f) Duration of the activity;
>
> (g) Any other pertinent information requested by the ATC facility.

There are no regulations for launches/operator to obtain a specific license if the model rocket motor complies with those in the quoted text.

While this regulation says you don't *have to* notify anybody, since you are expecting a significant altitude flight (and speaking as a pilot), it would be *nice* if you did notify them, especially if you are within a few miles of an airport or airway.

Comment: Do they define what constitutes a "slow-burning propellant" anywhere?  That seems (at least as a layman) ambiguous.

Comment: @RyanM The FAA doesn't define it unfortunately, and it doesn't look like the National Association of Rocketry (NAR) does either.